# js doesnt recognize variable inside <script> .. </script>

Tags: javascript, mongodb

I'm connecting to mongodb on my server.js:

```
var db;
MongoClient.connect('url...', (err, database) => {
    if(err) 
        return console.log(err);

    db = database;
    app.listen(3000, function() {
        console.log('listening on 3000');
    })
});
```

and using a script that handles onClick action, in another file .ejs:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function onClickFunctionA(idA,idB) {
        db.collection('Pictures').find().each(function(err, doc) {
            document.write(doc);
        }   
    }
</script>
```

The problem is that it doesn't recognize db which is declared in another file.

How can i make the script recognize db?

Comment: What do you mean with "*does't recognize*": what error do you get, and which code calls `onClickFunctionA`?

Comment: The top script is running on your server and the bottom script is running in the browser.

Comment: I cant access the db, it doesnt do nothing when i try printing the information using document.write(doc). Is there a way accessing the db from the script if its in the browser?

Comment: the onClickFunctionA is just some onClick i added to an image.

Comment: MongoDB is designed with intention of working 'behind' a server. That means no clients are supposed to directly access the Mongo Server. You can use Express to create a http server and implement a route which can query the MongoDB and return the result...This could be of help: https://zellwk.com/blog/crud-express-mongodb/  and  http://coenraets.org/blog/2012/10/creating-a-rest-api-using-node-js-express-and-mongodb/

Comment: Thanks, it helps. I saw the way they handled the click - and how they updated the db. Is there a way to also pass information (if the user click an image) like the picture id/name/etc ? so if i want to search the db for the picture id, and then update the data, for example..